How do I test to see if the Nix daemon is running and accepting requests?
(I'm asking here about the Nix package manager, not NixOS.)
What code (in Bash, or similar) can I run to see if the Nix daemon is running and able to accept requests from the current user? Ideally this will actually contact the daemon and verify that a (do-nothing) request was successfully executed, the way that e.g. docker version does. (As well as printing the client version information, docker version also contacts the server to fetch and print the server's version information.)
If the suggested code can also distinguish between daemon and no-daemon Nix installs, and return something that indicates that, even though no daemon is running, this user can use Nix anyway, that would be a bonus.
This need work only with Nix 2.0 and above; if it works with only some versions of Nix above 2.0, please state which versions it works with.
